# Authorization code doesn't work after restart OneDrive

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I'm trying to access OneDrive API from Python. 
I get authorization code:

```
url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=000000004811DD8C&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://samplewebsite/sample_page.php'
```

webbrowser.open(url)

Then I get access and auth tokens:

```
code = raw_input('Enter the code that appeared on the page: ')
url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf'
params = urllib.urlencode({
'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
'redirect_uri': 'http://samplewebsite/sample_page.php',
'client_secret': 'CLIENT_SECRET',
'code': code,
'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
})
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params).read()
data = json.loads(response)
```

After that I perform some code, which works fine. 
But after I close the application, and try to run it with the same authorization code, it raises an exception. What is the problem? Or do I have to get the new auth code every single time program runs?

Comment: Could you add more details about the exception you're seeing?

Comment: Here's the traceback I get when I try to use the auth key again. Line 20 is response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params).read()
https://www.dropbox.com/s/94jqwtzxueh3amm/shot_140519_204632.png

Answer (score 1):

Authorization codes expire in 1 hour.  It sounds like, for your scenario, you'll need to use a refresh token.  See the following documentation on our supported OAUTH 2.0 flows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631818.aspx

The following server side auth scenarios might also be helpful:

https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/tree/master/src/Web/Samples/OAuthServer

Comment: when do refresh tokens expire?

Comment: I don't see any server side auth in those links